# Firefox Silverlight div Reloads

Tags: silverlight, firefox, html, reload

In my application, I have a `div` (iframe) that I am hiding/showing when a button is clicked, which displays the content of my .xap file.  When I click the button to hide the `div`, I see the Silverlight frame disappear, and when I click the button to reshow the `div`, the Silverlight App reloads. Sometimes it'll appear blank too, but when I right-click the area, it has "Silverlight" listed in the context menu.

According to [this post](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/75856/180090.aspx), the reloading is a FireFox bug.

Does anyone have a work around to the reload?

In IE, the `div` appears without having to reload the Silverlight App.  I would like to get FireFox to have the same behavior.  More over, I would like to stop FireFox from making the `div` content blank.